# JMeter: No Class Def Found Error: kg/apc/jmeter/JMeterPluginsUtils

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to run a JMeter test and I keep getting the error listed below. I'm running in non-gui mode on an EC2 instance. I know I'm missing a .jar file and that's what is causing the error. But when I head over to Apache to look through their JMeter plugins, I can't find one that resolves this error.

```
2017-09-06 21:18:12,954 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/jmeter/JMeterPluginsUtils
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.<init>(PluginsCMDWorker.java:51) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.1.jar:?]
        at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:146) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar:?]
        at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:498) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JMeter Plugins installation is corrupt, double check you have `jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar` file in the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation. If not - you will have to re-install [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

Be aware that recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in Non-UI mode just remove the plugin element from your jmx file.