# kg/apc/jmeter/gui/IntegerInputVerifier error when i try to load templates

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I am using JMeter version 5.1.1 and when i want to open templates i get this error:
[image]

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087775/11725421), however the error still appears. This error appears when i try to open any template. As far as i know this means that class is not found. Can someone explain what exactly it means and what can i do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install clean [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Verify that Templates features is working as expected
3. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
4. Repeat step 2
5. Install plugins you need one by one (only ones you need as the more plugins you install - the slower JMeter startup would be). Repeat step 2 after each plugin installation.
6. If finally you will get templates feature working - that would be it. If not - consider reporting the issue to [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://jmeter-plugins.org/support/) and don't forget to include the content of the [*jmeter.log* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

Most probably the issue is cause by the [Variables From CSV File](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/VariablesFromCSV/) however I cannot reproduce it on my system.

Comment: How do you know which plugin is causing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, I had some corrupt plugins installed. I uninstalled JMeter and installed verified plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download your JMeter plugin manager from https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/

Before copy `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3` to JMeter's `lib/ext` folder:

Make sure there's no duplicate/older jar which start with `jmeter-plugins-manager`

If such jar exists -> remove it.

If it doesn't work check bin\jmeter.log for exceptions and edit your question